# How do I make my tikzpicture adapt to my column in an IEEE format

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no markers, domain=0:100, samples=100,
    axis lines*=left, xlabel=$Poistion within the Deck$, ylabel=$Probability of Occurence$,
    every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
    every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
    height=5cm, width=12cm,
    xtick={4,6.5}, ytick=\empty,
    enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
    grid = major
    ]
    \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=0:5.96] {gauss(6.5,1)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6.5,1)};


  \draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex](axis cs:4,0) -- node [fill=white] {$1.96\sigma$} (axis cs:5.96,0);
  \end{axis}

  \end{tikzpicture}
```

This is my plot as of now. It looks like this:

[image]

How am I supposed to make it fit within half the page. I just want to scale it horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: Have you tried `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm]` or whatever unit is applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put a figure like that (in the main text). Figures are normally shuffled in the final edit for publication, so that this is a no-no.

For a whole-page-width figure, you use

```
\begin{figure*}
... your tikzpicture here ...
\caption{whatever}
\label{mybigfig}
\end{figure*}
```

and then you say in the text

```
as you can see in Fig.~\ref{mybigfig}, fooing the bar leads to...
```

In the final publication phase, IEEE will ask for the separated PDFs for the figures and will scale, move and position them, so you are not supposed to do visual design... in other words, fo not worry where the figure goes. This is task for the professional publishing team at IEEE, and they'll do a good job with that.

Comment: Perfect answer! Since this is a draft for my professor, I guess I haven't been told yet!

Comment: Isn't the `figure*` environment used in IEEE to manually set double column floating equations (or images in this case)? I'm sure that there are journals in IEEE that support Tikz and you don't have to provide the separate image files (either PDF or eps).

Comment: Yes, `equation*` and `figure*` are for double column (full page width) elements. I do not know if they accept or not `tikz`, but generating PDFs is easy enough with `externalize`, so... ;-)